# CouchDB Authentication and Security

Tags: ubuntu, database, couchdb

i used this link to install CouchDB on virtual machine 
http://depth-first.com/articles/2010/01/28/pubcouch-install-couchdb-on-ubuntu-karmic-from-source/
everything goes fine, after that i tried to run this script to create DB

```
curl -X PUT http://localhost:5984/DB_name
```

the error message appeared 
{"error":"unauthorized","reason":"You are not a server admin."}

any suggestion to fix that

thanks

Comment: it seems you created an admin in local.ini (`couchdb -c` shows the location of the config files). If so, you have to provide the credentials like so: `curl -X PUT http://user:password@localhost:5984/DB_name`,´. BUT: is the version really this? apache-couchdb-0.10.1.tar.gz? The recent version is 1.6.1. What does the welcome message say when you run `curl http://localhost:5984` ?

Comment: thanks man!! i just add the username and the password,
it was version 1.6.1
{"couchdb":"Welcome","uuid":"8bce2833454b9c3dbeb51d4e9e6f5943","version":"1.6.1","vendor":{"name":"The Apache Software Foundation","version":"1.6.1"}}